# Is there a way to delete from a set and move the value to a temporary?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

Is there a way to delete an item in a set / map and get the former value as a temporary return value so that I can move() somewhere else ?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/extract

Comment: As far as I understand you can exctact a node with extract to be inserted somewhere else, but not the containing object.

Comment: you can move the value out of the node, there is no obligation to insert the node into another set

Comment: Are you really limited to C++11? `extract` isn't available until C++17.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, use `.extract()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <set>


int main()
{
    using elem = std::unique_ptr<int>;

    std::set<elem> set;
    set.insert(std::make_unique<int>(1));
    set.insert(std::make_unique<int>(2));
    set.insert(std::make_unique<int>(3));

    // auto iter = set.find(...);
    auto iter = set.begin(); // Some iterator.

    elem x = std::move(set.extract(iter).value());

    std::cout << *x << "\n\n"; // 1
    for (const auto &it : set)
        std::cout << *it << '\n'; // 2 3
}
```

I'm using non-copyable `std::unique_ptr<int>` as the element type to demonstrate that no copies are being made.